# Listing all running processes on server using PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, process, ps

I am trying to get a list of all processes currently running on my Ubuntu server using `PHP`. Ideally, I would like to get the following information:

- The Process ID
- The Command Used to Execute the Process
- The Arguments Given to the Process

I know that I can use `exec` to call `ps` to list the currently running processes.

```
exec('ps aux', $output);
```

However, the output is formatted with arbitrary number of spaces, so parsing it is not the easiest thing in the world.

I could potentially use `explode` or `preg_split` to parse, but **is there an easier way to get a list of all running processes using `php`, along with the process id, command, and arguments?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything simpler than `ps` with the right args, eg:`ahxwwo pid,command` which gives just the info you want, eg:

```
5911 tail -F /var/log/mail.log
```

If you want raw data you can read each file in `/proc/[123456789]*/cmdline`. For example,

```
$ cat -vet /proc/5911/cmdline
tail^@-F^@/var/log/mail.log^@
```

where the command arguments are separated by a null character.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the credit goes to [meuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008284/meuh).

---

```
ps ahxwwo pid,command
```

Gives me the three items I need, but it is still rather difficult to parse due to arbitrary space formatting.

However, it is possible to remove the space formatting.

```
ps ahxwwo pid:1,command:1
```

Using `explode` with a white space as the delimiter now guarantees that index 0 is the pid, and index 1 is the command, and the remaining indices are arguments.